# How to remove the default forward icon from navigationlink in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```swift
List {
  Section {
    NavigationLink(destination: changePassword(oldPassword: $password)) {
      HStack {
        Text("Şifreyi Değiştir")
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
      }
    }
    .foregroundColor(.orange)

    Button(action: {
      self.showingDeleteAccountPopup = true
    }) {
      HStack {
        Text("Hesabı Sil")
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65bZc.png)

how can I remove the default icon from the navigation link in the change password section

I have two buttons, change password and delete account. but one is Button and the other is NavigationLink, the icons look different because of this difference. i want to use the same icon in both places. how do i remove the default icon from the navigation link in that section?

Comment: You don’t need a NavigationLink if you have a Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, just replace the `NavigationLink` with this:

```
HStack {
    Text("Şifreyi Değiştir")
    Spacer()
    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")                 
}
.foregroundColor(.orange)
.overlay {
    NavigationLink(destination: {changePassword( oldPassword : $password ) }, label: { EmptyView() })
        .opacity(0)
}
```

(Code based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66231256/15372665))

Comment: It worked for me, thank you